# how to extract a date from text abstracted of a web page using Microsoft power automate?

Tags: web-scraping, power-automate

I have this data extracted from a particular web page

```
Document Name
*Created Date/Uploaded Date
201647034526-RELEVANT DOCUMENTS [27-09-2022(online)].pdf
27/09/2022
201647034526-US(14)-HearingNotice-(HearingDate-14-12-2020).pdf
17/10/2021
201647034526-IntimationOfGrant31-12-2020.pdf
31/12/2020
201647034526-PatentCertificate31-12-2020.pdf
31/12/2020
201647034526-Written submissions and relevant documents [29-12-2020(online)].pdf
29/12/2020
201647034526-Correspondence to notify the Controller [11-12-2020(online)].pdf
11/12/2020
201647034526-FORM-26 [11-12-2020(online)].pdf
11/12/2020
201647034526-FORM 3 [05-12-2020(online)].pdf
05/12/2020
201647034526-Annexure [09-09-2019(online)].pdf
09/09/2019
201647034526-CLAIMS [09-09-2019(online)].pdf
09/09/2019
201647034526-COMPLETE SPECIFICATION [09-09-2019(online)].pdf
09/09/2019
201647034526-FER_SER_REPLY [09-09-2019(online)].pdf
09/09/2019
201647034526-OTHERS [09-09-2019(online)].pdf
09/09/2019
201647034526-FORM 3 [11-06-2019(online)].pdf
11/06/2019
201647034526-FER.pdf
23/05/2019
201647034526-AMENDED DOCUMENTS [04-01-2019(online)].pdf
04/01/2019
201647034526-FORM 13 [04-01-2019(online)].pdf
04/01/2019
201647034526-RELEVANT DOCUMENTS [04-01-2019(online)].pdf
04/01/2019
201647034526-FORM 18 [27-03-2018(online)].pdf
27/03/2018
Form 3 [03-03-2017(online)].pdf
03/03/2017
Correspondence by Agent_Form30_04-01-2017.pdf
04/01/2017
Other Patent Document [29-12-2016(online)].pdf
29/12/2016
201647034526.pdf
14/10/2016
Description(Complete) [12-10-2016(online)].pdf
12/10/2016
Form 13 [12-10-2016(online)].pdf
12/10/2016
Marked Copy [12-10-2016(online)].pdf
12/10/2016
201647034526 Abstract 07-10-2016.pdf
07/10/2016
201647034526 Claims 07-10-2016.pdf
07/10/2016
201647034526 Description Complete 07-10-2016.pdf
07/10/2016
- **201647034526 Form-13 07-10-2016.pdf**
07/10/2016
201647034526 Form-2 07-10-2016.pdf
07/10/2016
Description(Complete) [07-10-2016(online)].pdf
07/10/2016
Form 3 [07-10-2016(online)].pdf
07/10/2016
Form 5 [07-10-2016(online)].pdf
07/10/2016
Power of Attorney [07-10-2016(online)].pdf
07/10/2016
Note: The displayed "Created Date/Uploaded Date" is dynamic in nature and depends upon the operating system environment of storage. For more information, please contact the Patent office of the respective jurisdiction
```

I want the above highlighted text as the output.

How do I do this in power automate?

Can someone help me how to deal with this?

I explored split() method in power automate and it wasn't working.
Even tried to paste it in an excel column and still wasn't working.

I'm referring to power automate desktop.

Comment: Are you referring to PowerAutomate desktop or cloud flows?

Comment: Power Automate Desktop.